# игра на JavaScript как сделать движение по параболе?

Tags: javascript, html, разработка-игр

пишу флаппи бёрдс и пока не получается сделать взлёты и падения как в настоящей игре, гравитация привязана к кнопке

```js
var Bird;
var Pipes = [];
var Score;

function startGame() {

  Bird = new component(30, 30, "bird.png", 10, 120, "image");
  Background = new component(480, 750, "background.png", 0, 0, "image");
  Bird.gravity = 0; //for start
  Score = new component("30px", "cooper", "orange", 5, 40, "text");
  GameArea.start();
}
var GameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480; // GameArea width
    this.canvas.height = 380; // GameArea height
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0; //start spase before bird
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20); //game speed
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  this.type = type;
  if (type == "image") {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = color;
  }
  this.score = 0;
  this.width = width; // width all components
  this.height = height; // height all components
  this.speedY = 0; //bird speedY
  this.x = x; // pipes layout x
  this.y = y; // pipes layout y
  this.gravity = 0;
  this.gravitySpeed = 0;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = GameArea.context;


    if (type == "image") {
      ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }

    if (this.type == "text") { //variable for graphic
      ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
    }
  }

  this.newPos = function() { //manage bird altitude
    this.gravitySpeed = this.gravity;
    //this.gravitySpeed = Bird.News() ;

    this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
    this.hitBottom();
    this.hitUpper();
  }
  this.hitBottom = function() { //stop border down
    var rockbottom = GameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
    if (this.y > rockbottom) {
      this.y = rockbottom;
      this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    }
  }

  this.hitUpper = function() { //stop border up
    if (this.y <= 0) {
      this.y = 0;
      this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    }
  }


  this.crashWith = function(otherobj) { //crash with pipe
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    var DownBorder = GameArea.canvas.height - 1;
    var UpBorder = 0;



    if (((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) && ((mytop > UpBorder) && (mybottom < DownBorder))) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;

  for (i = 0; i < Pipes.length; i += 1) { //crashWith Pipes and border
    if (Bird.crashWith(Pipes[i])) {
      return;
    }

  }
  GameArea.clear();
  Background.newPos();
  Background.update();
  GameArea.frameNo += 1;

  if (GameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
    x = GameArea.canvas.width;
    minHeight = 20;
    maxHeight = 200;
    height = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxHeight - minHeight + 1) + minHeight);
    minGap = 50;
    maxGap = 200;
    gap = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxGap - minGap + 1) + minGap);
    Pipes.push(new component(20, height, "green", x, 0));
    Pipes.push(new component(20, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < Pipes.length; i += 1) {
    Pipes[i].x += -1;
    Pipes[i].update();
  }
  // + GameArea.frameNo;
  Score.text = "SCORE: " + GameArea.frameNo;
  Score.update();
  Bird.newPos();
  Bird.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
  if ((GameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function Up(n) {
  Bird.gravity = n;
}

function News() {
  Bird.gravity = 0.1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Flappy Bird</title>

  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid #111111;
      background-color: #00FAFF;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="startGame()">
  <br>

  <button onmousedown="Up(-1.5)" onmouseup="Up(1.5)">Up</button>

</body>

</html>
```